# How many non-isomorphic finite groups with exactly $n$ conjugacy classes are there?

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, elementary-number-theory, finite-groups, egyptian-fractions

> How many non-isomorphic finite groups with exactly $n$ conjugacy classes are there?

All I managed to prove was that their number is finite for all $n \in \mathbb{N}$:

Suppose $G$ has $n$ conjugacy classes $C_1, ... C_n$, and suppose $\forall i \leq n$ $g_i \in C_i$. Then $|C_i| = [G:C(g_i)]$. From that we can conclude, that $1 = |G|^{-1}(\sum_{i=1}^n |C_i|) = |G|^{-1}(\sum_{i=1}^n [G:C(g_i)])=\sum_{i=1}^n \frac{1}{C(g_i)}$. And it is known that there is only finitely many ways to partition $1$ into sum of $n$ Egyptian fractions.

Comment: Do you mean $\forall i\leq n$?

Comment: @ArnaudMortier, yes. I have now edited accordingly.

Comment: There is some information [here](https://groupprops.subwiki.org/wiki/There_are_finitely_many_finite_groups_with_bounded_number_of_conjugacy_classes) but probably not much more than you have discovered for yourself.

Comment: I think a number of papers have been written about this, the finite groups with exactly $n$ conjugacy classes have been determined for $n$ up to maybe $13$ or so, but it gets harder and harder the larger $n$ gets. Have a look at https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2620762/finite-groups-with-15-or-16-conjugacy-classes

Comment: This has been asked a bunch of times, here and on MO. Here's another one, for example: https://mathoverflow.net/questions/237499/constructing-the-largest-finite-group-with-a-fixed-number-of-conjugacy-classes

Comment: Have you had a look at those links, Yanior?

Comment: Are you still here, Yanior?

Comment: @GerryMyerson. Those links are indeed very helpful, and I think, I would have even had accepted your comment as an answer if it were an answer. Sorry for not responding for such a long time.